# Fake Perpetual Motion Device using an Electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, perpetual-motion

I was watching a video of one of those fake perpetual motion machines where a ball falls down a hole and then flies off a ramp back onto the starting platform.

As suspected, the large base is hiding an electromagnet.  Studying frames of one cycle it seems that the ball seems to suddenly accelerate in an unexpected way around where the blue arrow is pointing.

Here the rail touches the ground and the electromagnet looks to be switched on at that point due to a pressure sensor.  However, I am a bit confused how the magnet is working to accelerate the ball, can a magnet ''push'' a ball in this way?  How is energy loss due to friction being overcome?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Honestly the device seemed pretty good to me as two of the biggest topics side stepped is work/ energy with no dX (ie solid stress) and magnetism. Even though it's fake

Comment: It works like a rail gun to accelerate the marble. https://science.howstuffworks.com/rail-gun1.htm

Comment: Link to video ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the point where the acceleration happens? On the ones I've seen the ball appears to accelerate abnormally when passing through the hole, not at the bottom.

Comment: That's a different device with a motor in it, as it passes through the hole the motor accelerates the ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you switch on a magnetic field in the vicinity of a conductive object, you induce an [eddy current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current#Repulsive_effects_and_levitation) in the object. This, in turn, makes its own magnetic field. The polarity of this field opposes the polarity of the inducing field, so repulsion results.

Answer (score 3):

Another way that this might work is that an electromagnet is turned on when the ball passes through the hole in the platform. This electromagnet would accelerate the ball faster than gravity towards the bottom of the ramp. Before the ball reaches the lowest point in the ramp the electromagnet is switched off allowing the ball to continue around the rest of the ramp to be launched back to the platform with the extra momentum from the small amount of extra speed it got from the time when the electromagnet was turned on.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as there are at least two possible explanations of what is going on, how to tell which one is the actual explanation for what we see?  Can eddy currents be eliminated as a possibility because of the materials being used etc.?

Comment: Without having one of these units to look at it is hard to know for sure what mechanism is being used.

Comment: Yeah I have been thinking about purchasing one but it is a hundred dollars (bit expensive for a one-off purchase).  On Amazon the device looks to be classed as the ''induction version'', which I think is close enough to narrow down the mechanism.